# Confirmation page for Form submit?

Tags: forms, typo3

in Typo3 6.1 how can I define a confirmation page ("Your request has been sent") afert a form has been submitted?
In Version 6.0 there was an option Target Page in the Behaviour tab of the form - but I cant find something similar in version 6.1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the success-message by adding

```typoscript
messages.success = TEXT
messages.success.value = Testsuccess
```

To `postProcessor.1`

Complete code:

```typoscript
postProcessor {
    1 = mail
    1 {
        recipientEmail = recipient@email
        senderEmail = sender@email
        subject = Testmail
        messages.success = TEXT
        messages.success.value = Testsuccess
    }
}
```

You can also define `messages.error`, if something went wrong.